# Returning values in nested JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json

First let me start by saying that there are two parts to this problem, the second is mentioned at the end.

I want to get values for all associated strings with a specific name. Let me try and explain with some example JSON.

```
{
  "data": {
    "list": {
      "123": {
        "location": 123,
        "x": 0.1,
        "y": 0.2,
        "ids": [
          {
            "id_a": 123
            "id_b": 442
          },
          {
            "id_a": 123
            "id_b": 443
          },
          {
            "id_a": 123
            "id_b": 444
          }
        ]
      }
      "555": {
        "location": 555,
        "x": 0.6,
        "y": 0.4,
        "ids": [
          {
            "id_a": 555
            "id_b": 449
          },
          {
            "id_a": 555
            "id_b": 450
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to return an array of all the "id_b" values. This is my desired output:

```
array = [442, 443, 444, 449, 450]
```

The closest I've got is by using the following:

```
import json
import urllib.request as ur

file = ur.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(file.read())

r = []
r = data['data']['list']['123']['ids'][0]['id_b']
print(r)
```

where I would get 442. Removing [0] leaves me with 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str'. I could try and include a loop where [0] becomes [i] and i is the number of 'ids' but this number is not consistent for all locations.

I haven't been able to find any examples of Python being used with a JSON structure like this. If anyone knows of any resources that could help I'd happily start with those.

Also, the url in question changes daily, I have code in place which alters the url depending on the day. However, when the day is changed the object names under 'list' also changes, i.e., "123" could become "326". Likewise with 'location' and 'id_a'. These are all the same. "123" = "location" value = "id_a" value.

Is there a way to simply put all values with the string "id_b" into an array? That's ultimately what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are some formatting errors in your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no additional nesting than what is shown in your example, you can use a single list comprehension:

```
>>> d = json.load(open("tmp.json"))
>>> [i['id_b'] for v in d['data']['list'].values()
...            for i in v['ids']]
[442, 443, 444, 449, 450]
```

If order matters (though it *shouldn't*, since key order in JSON objects is undefined), you have to rely on Python 3.7's guaranteed iteration order for `dicts`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive approach:

```
def find_by_key(obj, key):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k == key:
                yield v

            else:
                yield from find_by_key(v, key)

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for sub in obj:
            yield from find_by_key(sub, key)

    else:
        return

print(list(find_by_key(data, 'id_b')))
```

Output:

```
[442, 443, 444, 449, 450]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was in the middle of going for a SQL approach to get the data (it's all in house but wanted to keep it URL specific for monitoring reasons). You're method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursive function

> Recursive function:
>
> Recursion is a way of programming or coding a problem, in which a
>   function calls itself one or more times in its body. Usually, it is
>   returning the return value of this function call.
>
> Termination condition: A recursive function has to terminate to be
>   used in a program. A recursive function terminates, if with every
>   recursive call the solution of the problem is downsized and moves
>   towards a base case. A base case is a case, where the problem can be
>   solved without further recursion.

```
def id_generator(dict_var, key):
    for k, v in dict_var.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for id_val in id_generator(v,key):
                yield id_val
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                yield item[key]

key = 'id_b'
print(list(id_generator(data, key)))
```

output:

```
[442, 443, 444, 449, 450]
```